# JQuery/Javascript get position of object in object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<ul class="paginering">
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vorige</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">1</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">2</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">3</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">4</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">5</a></li>
 <li>...</li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">14</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">15</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">16</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">17</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">18</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Volgende</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
function changeDisplay(element){
 var clickedLi = $(element).closest("li");
 var clickedPage = parseInt($(element).html());
 var pageList = $(".paginering li");
}
```

Now I want to check the inner HTML value of the item in pageList next to the position of clickedLi. Something like: `pageList(clickedLiPosition+1).html();` How do I do this?

**Edit:**
And, there may or may not be an `<a>` element inside the `<li>`. How do I only get the value between the `<a>`, or if it isn't there, than between the `<li>`?

Comment: When creating the elements you could give unique id like `id="display1"` `id="display2"` etc then access like `var pageList = $("#display" + (currentNumber + 1))`

Comment: I thought of this, but I wasn't sure if this is the perfect solution. If it's possible with just one JQuery statement or something (I don't know), isn't that more efficient than creating a variable number of ID's then?

Comment: @JNF `pageList.indexOf(clickedLi);` doen't work. Or am I doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use next() to get the innerHTML of the next element :

```js
function changeDisplay(element){
 var clickedLi = $(element).closest("li");
    alert(clickedLi.next().html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paginering">
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Vorige</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">1</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">2</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">3</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">4</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">5</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">14</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">15</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">16</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">17</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="changeDisplay(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">18</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Volgende</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great answer. How do I only get the '1', '2', '14', etc. without the `<a>` element? I could use `clickedLi.next("li").find("a").html()`, but there may be a `li` without an `<a>` element

Comment: Will there be only one child element inside li?

Comment: IF there is an element, there will only be one.

Comment: Ok i will reply with an edit as soon as possible

Comment: @Grafit check this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/xh6zug8o/1/ .In this fiddle also look at the 17 and 18 content li element.Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

use .index() to find its position among its siblings then use .eq(n+1) on the collection of all the siblings to find next one.

http://api.jquery.com/index/

http://api.jquery.com/eq/